# Modify Apache Airflow UI base code- Action buttons like Rerun, Success etc

Tags: user-interface, button, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

Can someone please tell me if we can modify Airflow UI base code. I want to modify "Trigger Dag"(play button), Success button etc.

My requirement is to stop someone from marking a job to success or from running a task from UI without any approval from my Manager. Currently I have the access to trigger a DAG on adhoc basis. I can also mark a task to success without any approval. I do not want to do that without any approval. We have to show approval mechanism to the audit team. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set RBAC and DAG level acces

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=ldap#rbac-ui-security

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/security.html?highlight=ldap#dag-level-role